# onSeek Method which provided from just_audio plugin does not work correctly with acc audio file

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

onSeek Method which provided from just_audio plugin  does not work correctly  with acc audio file

i have the following file audio `.mp3` which is normally seeking

```
myAudioPlayer.setUrl(url.mp3);
myAudioPlayer.play();

MyCustumSlider(
 onSeek(value){
  myAudioPlayer.seek(value) // here will correctly seek to any point i choice 
 }
)
```

but if i play audio has `acc` format so it is always will return from first duration point
in every time i seek on slider

in the fact i tried too many deference audio format and they were all seeking correctly but not with acc format ..

How can i solve that kind of issue guys :)

any links , suggestion , solutions kindly lemme learn from your experience

best regards   :)

Comment: Yes you are right , i have the same issue